# PHP mysql_real_escape_string() returning `NULL`

Tags: php

I'm using PHP Version 5.1.6 and trying to escape a query string from my `$_GET` array. However my script is returning a `NULL` after it's escaped.

It seems that `mysql_escape_string()` works fine, but it's deprecated, so I don't want to use it.

Having checked over the `phpinfo()` the MySQL lib is all loaded fine from what I can see. Has anyone experienced this kind of thing before?

```
$term = $_GET['q'];

var_dump($term); // string(7) "richard" 
echo "<br />";

$sterm = mysql_real_escape_string($term, $db);

var_dump($sterm); // NULL
```

It's very strange to me, I can't imagine why this function wouldn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you have a MySQL connection running? That is a [requirement for `mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to work:

> **Note**: A MySQL connection is required before using `mysql_real_escape_string()` otherwise an error of level `E_WARNING` is generated, and `FALSE` is returned. If `$link_identifier` isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that `var_dump()` would return `FALSE` rather than `NULL` ? I'm also following it with a MySQL query, which is running okay on the same var `$db`

Comment: Turns out there is a bug in the MySQL class in this project! It only connects when you run a query, so I've had to force a connection and pass that into the function.